# vuejs component not rendering in my laravel 5.3 blade page

Tags: php, jquery, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3 and vue 1.0.26 version and it is unable to load components into blade pages. It showing empty. I was just trying with given laravel example component.

If any body have solution please suggest.

my app-laravel.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app'
});
```

my blade page looks like

```
  <div class="col-10 text-muted">
 <div id="app">
                <example></example>
 </div>

            </div>
```

and am using gulp which looks like

```
elixir(mix => {
mix.sass('app.scss', 'public/css/app.min.css')
.scripts([
    '../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'libraries/datatables.responsive.js',
    'libraries/datatables.responsive.bootstrap4.js',
    '../../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js',
    'app.js',
], 'public/js/app.min.js');
});
```

my Example.vue file here

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    I'm an example component!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
 export default {
     ready() {
         console.log('Component ready.')
     }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot mount a Vue instance on the `body`. Put everything in a `<div id="app">` and mount to `#app`

Comment: even i tried with that also not working

Comment: Well, whatever the other issues are, mounting to the `body` definitely won't work

Comment: Also, use `vue.js` instead of `vue.min.js` so that you'll get error messages from Vue, which would be helpful to include

Comment: my app-laravel.js file
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

Comment: Ijust tried     not working<div id="app">
                    <example></example>
                    </div>

Comment: ya i will use vue.js

Comment: Link the contents of `Example.vue` please.

Comment: @TaylorFoster I have added the example.vue file code, can u plz check

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your Vue component file, try making these changes and see if you are still having problems.

```
<template> <!-- First open a template tag -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            I'm an example component!
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template> <!-- Close template tag -->

<script>
  // Try using module.exports instead of export default
  module.exports = {

  }    
</script>
```

Comment: No still having same issues. please suggest if find any other issues in that

Comment: Sorry all, I have not added <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script> in main layout file, now it is working fine Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You need to import vue first, write code like this

```
//import vue
import Vue from 'vue';

//register component
Vue.component('yourComponentName',require('./components/yourComponentName.vue').default);

//initialize vue
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```